# Maxent can't get past "javalang.ClassCastExeption: [D cannot be cast to [F" error message

Tags: arcgis-desktop, java, maxent

I have turned all stones I can think of how to solve this, and it feels like it should be something simple I am missing, but I just can't get Maxent to work.

When Maxent (v.3.4.3) reaches the step `"Extracting random background and sample data"` it stops and gives me the error:

```
Error reading file: C:\data.csv: javalang.ClassCastExeption: [D cannot be cast to [F
```

I formatted the csv files as specified in instructions to have only 3 columns: `species`, `longitude`, `latitude`. I have made sure that all rasters are in ASCII format, with the same projection, of the same extent, and with the same pixel size. I have even tried it with projected datasets and with unprotected geographic coordinate systems, both for the rasters and csv files. And I still get the same error.

Has anyone encountered a similar error or know why this happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try updating your Java version or, using a older maxent version

Comment: Thank you for your response! So it is a bug in the latest version of Maxent? Indeed, I downloaded an older version (3.2.19) of the software from the GitHub repository of archived releases (https://github.com/mrmaxent/Maxent/tree/master/ArchivedReleases) and it seems to have worked!

Comment: I think the latest version of Maxent requires the latest version of Java, so you have to update one or the other. Its also easier to just use an older version because not much changes in Maxent

Comment: Looks like I was using Java version 1.8.0_271 and I thought I downloaded it not long ago. The current version on the Java website is 1.8.0_281. Would that be outdated enough for Maxent 3.4.3 to not work?

Comment: i'm not sure to be honest but i had a similar issue and using an old version i happened to have in my computer worked